# How to secure "remember me" token in cookie without storing data in database?

Tags: cookies

I want to secure remember me token for my website. I have read many articles but all points to one thing that to map those two tokens in database. Is there any other way that can be used to secure the token without using database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use public key cryptography to sign the information on the server and then ask the browser to store that information as a cookie. You never need to share the private key to any clients for that. When restoring the session based on the cookie, the server can then verify the signature.

You could also encrypt the contents of the cookie with the same or a different key. Then only the server is able to decrypt what is stored in the browser, therefore even sensitive data can be sent there.

The most popular algorithm is RSA, but you should check out [ED25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/) that seems to be independent of any surveillance companies and organizations.

Comment: What if the secret key is known to the attacker? Is there any other way ?

Comment: Public key cryptography is not immune to the server being hacked and hackers gaining access to the secret key. You can use hardware wallets (like Yubikey) so that even the server code does not have access to the secret key.

Comment: I just want to know what are the possible methods that i can use to secure remember me token without using DB. Is this(cryptography) the only way i can do it? @wigy

Comment: If you do not want to keep a centralized DB of the authenticated sessions on your server, you will have a decentralized database. Since you cannot trust all your users and their browsers, you need to build a protocol that is resilient to malicious clients. Personally I do not know any other ways. Imagine a cookie that just contains the userId. Anyone could edit their cookie and use other sessions. These are the attacks you need to consider.

Comment: @Nick, if you think this answers your question, and this is the best answer you got, feel free to accept it as an answer by pressing the checkmark next to it. If you did not get the answer you wanted, edit your question. Thanks.